# Cannot stop MySQL Server. Lost PID file?

Tags: mysql, pid, sequelpro

When I put in mysql.server stop, I receive:

ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!

I had this happen this morning, so I uninstalled SQL and deleted homebrew.

And then, I reinstalled brew and reinstalled SQL. And it happened again.

I just started up a sql server, connected to it through SequelPro, made a couple databases in SequelPro and then closed my computer. Now that I'm back, I'm having this challenge and I'm not sure why.

Comment: check process here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390936/mysql-wont-shutdown-stop-server-error-mysql-server-pid-file-could-not-be-fo

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. I get the same error message when I try to stop the SQL server. When I do ps -ef | grep mysql, it shows there is one thing running but the PID number changes every time I run it. And when I go to kill the PID number it has, it says "No such process".

Comment: MySQL != SQL server. Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Is a MySQL server not a SQL server? I'm new to this.

Comment: I think HoneyBadger means MySQL is different from *Microsoft SQL Server*, and the tag [tag:sql-server] is used on Stack Overflow to refer to the Microsoft product, not SQL servers in general.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Any tips for the PID file?